# Ubuntu 20.04 geolocation not working on some web browsers

Tags: windows, firefox, chromium, geolocation, gnome-maps

I use Ubuntu 20.04 and I am working on a web app that requires geolocation, so I need to get my current location from the web browser. I noticed that I could not get my position in Firefox using the JS geolocation api. Location services in the Settings->Privacy menu are enabled but I can see no app using them in the list below the on-off button. I have tried the following to narrow down the possible causes:

- Installed chromium. No result
- Checked https://www.where-am-i.net/ on both browsers to make sure that it was not an HTTPS issue. No result
- Installed Gnome Maps. Location is shown correctly
- Tried Firefox or Chrome on Windows on the same machine. Location is shown correctly

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score -1):

Solutions:

1. Remove default Firefox and install snap version. Location is shown correctly
2. Install Opera browser. Location is shown correctly